# I tried creating merge sort using vectors for a school project. Didn't get the desired output

Tags: c++, c++17, codeblocks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
void sort(vector <int> &v, int i, int j, int end2)
{
    vector <int> v1;
    int start1=i, start2=j, end1=j;
    while((start1<end1)||(start2<end2))
    {
        if((start1<end1)&&(start2<end2))
        {
            if(v[start1]<v[start2])
            {
                v1.push_back(v[start1]);
                start1++;
            }
            else if (v[start1]==v[start2])
            {
                v1.push_back(v[start1]);
                start1++;
                start2++;
            }
            else
            {
                v1.push_back(v[start2]);
                start2++;
            }
        }
        else if((start1<end1)&&(start2>=end2))
        {
            v1.push_back(v[start1]);
            start1++;
        }
        else if((start1>=end1)&&(start2<end2))
        {
            v1.push_back(v[start2]);
            start2++;
        }
    }
    int s=i;
    while(s<end2)
    {
        v[i]=v1[i];
        i++;
    }
}
void mergeSort(vector <int> &v, int s)
{
    int low, end2, high;
    for(int k=2;k<=s;k=k*2)
    {
        for(int i=0;i+k-1<s;i=i+k)
        {
            low=i;
            high=i+k;
            end2=i+2*k;
            sort(v, low, high, end2);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    vector <int> v;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the no. of elements you want to sort\n";
    cin>>n;
    int d;
    cout<<"Enter the values\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>d;
        v.push_back(d);
    }
    int s= v.size();
    mergeSort(v, s);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<v[i]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

So i wrote this code on codeblocks, when i tried executing it, it asks me to enter the values to be sorted. i enter those values and suddenly the screen shows segmentation faults and closes the program. Please help me correct this code for merge sort. i have recently started using stls and get confused while using them.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? That will make finding the source of these bugs much easier.

Comment: Code::blocks has a very nice built-in debugger, this will be a great place to start!

Comment: @SaiSreenivas  i made that function to keep track of how many times 2 way merging is done

Comment: Wow, so many (redundant) (parentheses). `while ((start1 < end1) || (start2 < end2))` doesn't need those inner parentheses. `while (start1 < end1 || start2 < end2)` says exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's this piece of code for?

```
int s=i;
while(s<end2)
{
    v[i]=v1[i];
    i++;
}
```

Should just be removed IMHO.

Shouldn't this code

```
        else if (v[start1]==v[start2])
        {
            v1.push_back(v[start1]);
            start1++;
            start2++;
        }
```

actually be this?

```
        else if (v[start1]==v[start2])
        {
            v1.push_back(v[start1]);
            v1.push_back(v[start2]);
            start1++;
            start2++;
        }
```

Otherwise your final array is going to be shorter than your original array.

Food for thought, as already said you should use a debugger to investigate.